# Find sum of all permutations

Tags: combinatorics

We call two arrays A and B with length n almost equal if for every i (1 <= i <= n)

```
CA(A[i]) = CB(B[i]). 
CX[x] equal to number of index j (1 <=j <= n) such that X[j] < x.
```

For two permutations P1 and P2 we define a function F(P1, P2) that is equal to number of pairs (l,r) (1 <= l <= r <= n) such that P1[l..r] is almost equal to P2[l..r] and array P1[l..r] contain not more then E inversions.

**Inversions** : Inversion Count for an array indicates – how far (or close) the array is from being sorted. If array is already sorted then inversion count is 0. If array is sorted in reverse order that inversion count is the maximum.
Formally speaking, two elements a[i] and a[j] form an inversion if a[i] > a[j] and i < j.

Now we need to find what is the sum F(P1,P2) by all possible permutations P1, P2 from n elements.

Example : Let N=2 and E=2 then here answer will be 10.

I want a formula to do this question.

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you are looking for the number of choices $1\le l\le r\le n$ and permutations $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ such that the terms $\sigma_1l, \sigma_1(l+1), \ldots, \sigma_1r$ are in the same order as the terms $\sigma_2l, \sigma_2(l+1), \ldots, \sigma_2r$, and there are at most $e$ involutions in $\sigma_1l, \sigma_1(l+1), \ldots, \sigma_1r$.

Suppose there are $f_e(k)$ permutations in $S_k$ with at most $e$ involutions.

Then for a given $1\le l\le r\le n$, and a given permutation $\tau\in S_{r+1-l}$,
the number of permutations $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ such that $\sigma_1l, \ldots, \sigma_1r$ and $\sigma_2l, \ldots, \sigma_2r$ are in the same order as $\tau1, \ldots, \tau(r+1-l)$ is $\frac{n!}{(r+1-l)!}^2$.

Thus the answer is $\Sigma_{1\le l\le r\le n}f_e(r+1-l)\frac{n!}{(r+1-l)!}^2$.

Gathering all terms with the same $r-l$ together, we see that the answer is

$\Sigma_{1\le k\le n}(n+1-k)f_e(k)\frac{n!}{k!}^2.$

In particular, for $n=2$ and $e=2$, $f_2(1)=1$ and $f_2(2)=2$ so the answer is

$2\times1\times\frac{2}{1}^2+1\times2\times\frac{2}{2}^2=10.$

Comment: How are you finding fe(k)?PLease explin what is k here : Suppose there are fe(k) permutations in Sk with at most e involutions.

Comment: Also whats Sk here?

Comment: @BrainJefferson ALso explain how in this example f2(1) = 1 and f2(2) = 2